# Using a database in an android app

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse

I'm new to android development. I've started with an app on eclipse using java which uses a database of locations. My question is, how would I be able to connect my android app which to the database. Also suggest a suitable way of creating the database. Can I create it in mysql and then import in eclipse?

Comment: try reading the docs: [Android: Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here.](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

I hope this will help you.

If you want to use `MySQL` to insert the data then use `web service` to send data in `XML` format from `android` to `web service`.

Answer (score -1):

This link should explain everything that you need!

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

If you're just using this database for your application to store data, sqlite is a much better choice than mysql and integrates simply into android. I used the very same link above awhile back when I was getting into this stuff. The tutorial is structured in a very easy to read manner and explains everything as it goes. Good luck.